# Search within Jar file

Tags: jar, full-text-search

I have a lot of Jar files and I need to search for a particular class file within that JAR files? Can someone please suggest a Tool to do this?

Comment: If you are using Linux, then you can use `jar` command along with `grep` as follows : `jar tvf /path/to/jar.jar | grep -i ClassName`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use any IDE.(I will suggest [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)).

In eclipse set all jar files to your projects build path and use File Search option to find class.

In Eclipse, You can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open "**Open Type**" dialog, which let you search for a class in current workspace.

Answer (score 8):

I know, it's an old topic but it may help people who google and come here.

You can try `zfind` utility: http://sourceforge.net/projects/zfind

It supports most common archive/compressed files (`jar`, `zip`, `tar`, `tar.gz` etc) and unlike many other `jar` or `zip` finders, supports nested `zip` files (`zip` within `zip`, `jar` within `jar` etc) till unlimited depth.

Disclaimer: I wrote the utility, but I believe it does the job nicely. I won't suggest it otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

My situation is searching text in the class in jars.
I google for a while and come here,and finally find that [JD-GUI](http://jd.benow.ca/) is perfect for my case.
Hope that help anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse can do it, just create a project and drop your jar files on the projects classpath. Then you can easily find the classes.

Or you just unzip you file and search for the filename in the directory with:

`unzip foo.jar find foo/ -iname "*MyClass*" -print`

Answer (score 0):

In `bash` you can use this for a single jar file

```
jar -tvf myjar.jar | grep MyClass
```

For multiple files, wrap the above in a loop.

HTH